# $("#tableID").load(location.href + " #tableID") is creating new table instead of refreshing existing one

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I need to refresh a particular data table. There will be a button to enter a message in textbox. On click of saveMessage button , that message will be saved in databbase. Later I tried

> $("#tableID").load(location.href + " #tableID")

so that the table will get updated. I'm using data table , which has sort option. After executing above line , sort option used to get disappeared. On inspecting the table I found a new table used to overlap on existing table.

I also tried

> $('#tableID').DataTable().ajax.reload();

It didnt work. can someone please help me to refresh that data table without creating new table.
Thanks in regards.

Comment: $('body').find('table').DataTable().ajax.reload(); Try this. You can also use table id instead of table

Comment: Got this alert "Invalid JSON response."

Comment: Try to destroy before initialized datatable $('#TableID').DataTable().destroy();

Comment: Got the same alert and also extra sort buttons in table. Please help me @TruptiBarad

Comment: Check your ajax response formate. For more info https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/1